# How to write a class that may accept a function pointer and/or functor just like a smart pointer does for custom deleter?

Tags: c++, boost, function-pointers, functor, tr1

I'm trying to write a class that accepts a a function pointer AND/OR a functor to be user later by the class.
To illustrate better what I'd like to do:

```
template <typename T> class Holder {
private:
  T *m_ptr;
  <something> m_func;

public:
  Holder(T *ptr) : m_ptr(ptr), m_func(NULL) {
  }

  Holder(T *ptr, <something> func) : m_ptr(ptr), m_func(func) {
  }

  ~Holder() {
    if (m_func) {
      m_func(m_ptr);
    } else {
      delete m_ptr;
    }
  }
};
```

Considering I'd like to handler objects of this type:

```
class MyClass {
public:
  void describe() {
    cout << "Bla bla bla ...";
  }
};
```

Then I could use it this way:

```
class MyClassFunctor {
public:
  void operator()(MyClass *ptr) const {
    cout << "Deleting ptr using functor: ";
    ptr->describe();
    cout << endl;
    delete ptr;
  }
};

int main() {
  MyClass *myclass = new MyClass();
  MyClassFunctor functor();
  {
    Holder<MyClass> holder(myClass, functor);
  }
  cout << "I'm out of context now!" << endl;
}
```

AND (not or) this way:

```
void myClassDeleter(MyClass *ptr) {
  cout << "Deleting ptr using function pointer: ";
  ptr->describe();
  cout << endl;
  delete ptr;
}

int main() {
  MyClass *myclass = new MyClass();
  {
    Holder<MyClass> holder(myClass, &myClassDeleter);
  }
  cout << "I'm out of context now!" << endl;
}
```

Notice I'd like to be able to use both approaches: Functors AND function pointers.

I'd say it is possible, since this is what Boost::shared ptr and tr1::shared_ptr does.
I tried digging into Boost::shared_ptr code, but I couldn't really understand how they do it.

I'm sorry if my code is wrong or seems to be naive. I tried to explain the problem as concisely as possible, so code correctness wasn't my main focus here (I realize this is important).

Notice I don't even think about rewriting a smart pointer class from scratch. This is out of question here, since I know it is not a wise call.
I'm interested in knowing how to do it so I can use this mechanism for other purposes. Smart pointers were simply the simplest use of that I could remember.

For now, I'd like to avoid using boost and C++11. Is it possible to do it using plain c++03?

Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: you can use `boost::function`, see here for example:  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/function/tutorial.html#idp95743864

Comment: And also there is `std::function` in c++11 http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

Comment: And `MyClassFunctor functor();` doesn't do what you think it does. Lose the parens.

Comment: @g-makulik there is no good reason to do that and it would make code unnecessarily complex - imagine if every time you declared a smart pointer you'd have to specify yet another template parameter.

Comment: The boost::function and C++11 std::function helps a lot. However, I was thinking about doing that in plain C++03. Is it possible?

Comment: A friend told me to read about type erasure. He said this is probably the way to go. I'll get back as soon as I understand it.

Comment: Indeed, Type Erasure is the way to go. Check my answer, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: Type Erasure.

The implementation is not that simple, and I suggest reading about Type Erasure a little (as I just did!).

First of all, you need to create the Type Erased apparatus:

```
class ActionBase {
    public:
        virtual ~ActionBase() { }
        virtual bool DoIt() = 0;
};

template<typename P>
class ActionP : public ActionBase {
    private:
        P *ptr;
    public:
        ActionP(P *p) : ptr(p) { }

        virtual bool DoIt() {
            cout << "Standard action (nothing to do)..." << endl;
            return true;
        }
};

template<typename P, class A>
class ActionPA : public ActionBase {
    private:
        P *ptr;
        A action;

    public:
        ActionPA(P *p, A & a ) : ptr(p), action(a) { }

        virtual bool DoIt() { return action(ptr); }
};
```

Then you can declare the Holder class:

```
template<typename T>
class Holder {
    private:
        // Avoid object copy and assignment.
        Holder(const Holder<T> &rhs);
        Holder<T>& operator=(const Holder<T> &rhs);

    protected:
        T* ptr;
        ActionBase *action;

    public:
        template<typename U> Holder(U *ptr) : ptr(ptr), action(new ActionP<U>(ptr)) { }

        template<typename U, class A> Holder(U* p, A a) : ptr(p), action(new ActionPA<U, A>(p, a)) { }

        virtual ~Holder() { delete ptr; delete action; }

        bool DoAction() {
            return this->action->DoIt();
        }
};
```

Then you can use it passing function pointers, functors, or even nothing:

```
template<typename T>
class ActionFunctor {
    public:
        bool operator()(T* instance) const {
            cout << "Action operator..." << endl;
            // Simple operation: set the value to 3 times the original value (works for int and string!!)
            instance->Set(instance->Get() + instance->Get());
            return true;
        }
};

template<typename T>
bool ActionFunc(T* instance) {
    cout << "Action function..." << endl;
    // Simple operation: set the value to 3 times the original value (works for int and string!!)
    instance->Set(instance->Get() + instance->Get() + instance->Get());
    return true;
}

int main() {
    {
        cout << "First test:" << endl;
        ActionFunctor<X> actionX;
        Holder<X> x1(new X(1), &ActionFunc<X>);
        Holder<X> x2(new X(10), actionX);
        Holder<X> x3(new X(100));
        x1.DoAction();
        x2.DoAction();
        x3.DoAction();
    }
    {
        cout << "Second test:" << endl;
        ActionFunctor<Y> actionY;
        Holder<Y> y1(new Y("A"), &ActionFunc<Y>);
        Holder<Y> y2(new Y("BB"), actionY);
        Holder<Y> y3(new Y("CCC"));
        y1.DoAction();
        y2.DoAction();
        y3.DoAction();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
First test:
X constructor: 1
X constructor: 10
X constructor: 100
Action function...
Action operator...
Standard action (nothing to do)...
X desstructor: 100
X desstructor: 20
X desstructor: 3
Second test:
Y constructor: "A"
Y constructor: "BB"
Y constructor: "CCC"
Action function...
Action operator...
Standard action (nothing to do)...
Y destructor: "CCC" ...
Y destructor: "BBBB" ...
Y destructor: "AAA" ...
```

Hope it's useful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious solution is to use `boost::function` or `std::function`. However, if you want to avoid the overhead these objects add, you can make `Holder` to accept a *Callable* as a template argument:

```
template <typename T, class F> 
class Holder 
{
private:
  T *m_ptr;
  F m_func;
//...
```

Of course, you'd have to make a helper function that would deduct the actual type of the *Callable*:

```
// depending on the nature of your functors, consider passing by const &
template<typename T, class F>
Holder<T, F> make_holder(T *t, F f)
{
  return Holder<T, F>(t, f);
}
```

Use it like this:

```
auto holder = make_holder(myClass, &myClassDeleter);
// or:
auto holder = make_holder(myClass, functor);
```

Comment: That seems to be promising.
I wonder how boost does that using C++03 without a helper function.
Do you have any clue?

Comment: @Marcus If you mean how `shared_ptr` accepts custom deleters, that's exactly how it does that. The "helper function" there is a parametrized constructor (like `template<class Y, class D> shared_ptr( Y * p, D d )`). Remember that the only way to deduct argument types is to use a [member-]function template.

Comment: Exactly Igor, however you need to use Type Erasure to be able to use both function pointers and functors. Check the solution I posted.

Comment: @Marcus No, you don't. Type-erasure is actually a *non-template* object (not parametrized by the callable type) that would allow to store any callable, so it's effectively `std::function`. But if you're fine with such an overhead - just use `std::function`, no need to reinvent it. OTOH, with a template solution you have no such an overhead (but there are other known trade-offs).

Comment: Understand Igor. The problem with std::function is that it is c++11 only, insn't it? I'm trying to avoid c++11 for now since most of the time I program no for PC, but embedded c++. Even tough, you are right. Thanks for your help.